when the phone charging to 100%, adb bugreport >bugreport.zip,but the bugreport. zip does not have a log of the charging. phase why is this?
When the phone charging to 100%, I use the adb bugreport command to get the bugreport.zip, but the bugreport. zip does not have a log of the charging phase. why is this?
test step: on android phone, androi version is 14
Charge my phone to 100%  until the phone stops charging
use abd bugreport command to get ugreport.
use battery-historian analyze bugreport
The report does not contain logs for the charging phase, only after unplugging the charger
What should I do if I want to keep an eye on the background running during the charging phase? The test must be charged to 100% until the phone stops charging
